# Replace all occurrences of * a string

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do `string.replace()` on the `*` character.  The string has multiple occurrences of the character and so I need to do a global replace, but if I do what seems natural it produces the comment tag.

```
x.replace(/*/g, '');
```

How do you work around this?

Comment: Escape asterik `x = x.replace(/\*/g, '');`

Comment: Escape the asterisk. `x.replace(/\*/g, '');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to escape the `*`

`*` is a reserved lookup item:

> `*`    Matches the preceding character 0 or more times. Equivalent to {0,}.
>
> For example, /bo*/ matches 'boooo' in "A ghost booooed" and 'b' in "A
>   bird warbled", but nothing in "A goat grunted".

[See Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

```
var jamie = '* 8 * *';
jamie = jamie.replace(/\*/g, '');
// 8
```